# Can not figure out an exception

Tags: java, android, multithreading, exception, concurrency

I am writing simple code to **asynchronously** write logs to file, but find it difficult to figure out one issue.

I get `java.util.NoSuchElementException` in `logNodes.removeFirst()`. How can this happen if I check if the list is empty?

This issue mostly occurs if I log very frequently.

If anyone can explain to me why is this happening, it would be very appreciated.

My code:

```
private static class FileLogger extends Thread {
    private File logFile;
    private PrintWriter logWriter;
    private final LinkedList<LogNode> logNodes = new LinkedList<>();

    public FileLogger(Context context) {
        String dateString = (String) DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss", new Date());
        File logsDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "logs");

        if (logsDir.exists()) {
            for (File file : logsDir.listFiles()) {
                file.delete();
            }
        }

        try {
            logFile = new File(logsDir, dateString + ".log");
            if (!logFile.exists()) {
                logFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                logFile.createNewFile();
            }

            logWriter = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(logFile));
            start();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }
    }

    public void log(Date date, String tag, String msg) {
        if (isAlive()) {
            logNodes.addLast(new LogNode(date, tag, msg));
            synchronized (this) {
                this.notify();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (logNodes.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        this.wait();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    logWriter.flush();
                    logWriter.close();
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                LogNode node = logNodes.removeFirst();
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.US);
                logWriter.println(String.format(
                        "%s %s.%s", dateFormat.format(node.date), node.tag, node.msg
                ));
                logWriter.flush();
            }
        }
    }

    private class LogNode {
        final Date date;
        final String tag;
        final String msg;

        public LogNode(Date date, String tag, String msg) {
            this.date = date;
            this.tag = tag;
            this.msg = msg;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a concurrency issue. Instead of doing the hard work of handling a Thread and queuing nodes yourself, you can use a `ExecutorService` (in your case a [singleThreadExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor--)) will work). You can submit new nodes to it and just implement a `Runnable` that does the I/O part. The rest is free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reason

You did not synchronize mutiple `log` threads.

Suppose you have thread1 and thread2:

1. thread1 has written node1 into the queue.
2. `FileLogger` noticed node1 when it call `isEmpty`, while thread2 did
   not notice it.
3. thread2 think this list is empty, and let the list's first and
   last node be node2, which means node1 has be overwritten.
4. Since you did not has any other synchronization, node2 might not be noticed by `FileLogger`, `NoSuchElementException` will be thrown.

### Solution

Instead implementing a blocking queue yourself, try use [`BlockigQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) provided by `java.util.concurrent`, let it do the synchronization for you.

```
private static class FileLogger extends Thread {
    private File logFile;
    private PrintWriter logWriter;
    private final BlockingQueue<LogNode> logNodes = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    public FileLogger(Context context) {
        String dateString = (String) DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss", new Date());
        File logsDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "logs");

        if (logsDir.exists()) {
            for (File file : logsDir.listFiles()) {
                file.delete();
            }
        }

        try {
            logFile = new File(logsDir, dateString + ".log");
            if (!logFile.exists()) {
                logFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                logFile.createNewFile();
            }

            logWriter = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(logFile));
            start();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }
    }

    public void log(Date date, String tag, String msg) {
        if (isAlive()) {
            logNodes.add(new LogNode(date, tag, msg));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                LogNode node = logNodes.take();
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.US);
                logWriter.println(String.format(
                        "%s %s.%s", dateFormat.format(node.date), node.tag, node.msg
                ));
                logWriter.flush();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                logWriter.flush();
                logWriter.close();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the solution. Now it seems work ok.